# Will I face any trouble consuming SOAP WS manually?

Tags: xml, soap, integration, axis

There's this SOAP RPC v1.2 which I have to integrate to. Not a complex one, two operations only.

My question is fairy simple, even though I haven't seem to figure it out: **Is it wrong or trouble to implement this integration code on my own, instead of using stuff like Apache Axis ou CXF?**

It seems to me that's just XML going back and forth over TCP... Am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems to me that's just XML going back and forth over TCP... Am I wrong?

You are not wrong. It's XML over HTTP. You can populate values into an XML template to send the request and then parse the XML response. Whether or not this is easier to implemented and maintain may depend on your application, but it's usually easier to generate stub classes from the WSDL file.

Answer (score 1):

SOAP and RPC are protocols (it means everything is well defined by rules and steps), so yeah, basically all you have to do is follow this rules and steps in your implementation and you should be completely fine.

And yep, both SOAP and RPC define XML as the standard format for data transfers, so  we could say that all you have to do are XML parsers to interpret the data you exchange.